# Compare Json to CSV File Headings and Populate

Tags: node.js, json, csv

Hi have the below JSON which I would like to match against a set of field names in CSV File and populate. I am getting the json data from an api and would like to create the set CSV file on the fly in node.js

CSV set Field names:

```
"Name", "ID", "PRODUCT 1", "PRODUCT 2", "PRODUCT 3"
```

JSON (manual example for simplicity, apologies if structure has errors):

```
[{
   name: 'Bob',
   id: '100',
   products: {[
       {item: 'product 1',
       qty: '3'},
       {item: 'product 2',
       qty: '2'}]
},{
   name: 'James',
   id: '200',
     products: {[
       {item: 'product 3',
       qty: '1'}]
}
```

Desired CSV populated:

CSV Fields:

```
"Name", "ID", "PRODUCT 1", "PRODUCT 2", "PRODUCT 3"
 Bob     100    3              2
 James   200                                1
```

Comment: Will the maximum number of products always be 3, and therefore the maximum number of CSV columns 5? Or will there be an unknown upper limit of products and you need to support _n_ columns per CSV dynamically according to the largest number of products for a given entry in a given API response?

Comment: Thank you for you reply, indeed the maximum number of products will be 3 and the maximum number of CSV columns will be 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would shape and flat the CSV columns, then parse and output using [json2csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv) and [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html).

```
const { parse } = require('json2csv');
const fs = require('fs');

const items = [
  {
    name: 'Bob',
    id: '100',
    products: [
      {
        item: 'product 1',
        qty: '3'
      },
      {
        item: 'product 2',
        qty: '2'
      }]
  }, {
    name: 'James',
    id: '200',
    products: [
      {
        item: 'product 3',
        qty: '1'
      }]
  }
];
// flatten the needed CSV columns
const flatten = items.map(item => {
  const i = {
    name: item.name,
    id: item.id
  };
  // pull out products
  item.products.forEach(product => {
    i[product.item] = product.qty;
  });

  return i;
});

// Declare the expected fields here
const fields = ['name', 'id', 'product 1', 'product 2', 'product 3'];

const csv = parse(flatten, { fields });

fs.writeFile('items.csv', csv, (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('CSV file saved');
});
```

Hope I've helped.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mas, I will try that, I suppose initially looking at this, I can see how to flatten, but then I am not sure howI would populate the quantities to the correct product CSV columns. However maybe I need to run your approach through at bit more and it will become clear. Thank you.

Comment: @FrankFerdinandMcGovern In ```flatten```, ```forEach``` will iterate over the item's products array, and then will append a new key/value to the newly created object ```i```, the key will be ```product.item``` value and its value will be ```product.qty``` value. Let me know if you face any other difficulties.

Comment: Thank you for the steer Mas, I going to try that now and will come back with results.

Comment: Wow, you know your stuff Mas, that works a dream (I have a up voted your great solution). However, I stupidly used a very basic JSON in my example and now I am struggling to adapt your code to work with my more complex json with 4 levels, anyway I will truck on as its not fair changing the question.

Comment: Actually I am gong to put it here (ignore if you want) I will try get it, but taking a while. My json has the structure below, its trips up when I feed: 'item.node.lineItems.edges.node.forEach' I get the following error to console: TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined                                                                       `[
  {
    node: {
      createdAt: '2020-02-24T12:53:20Z',
      name: '#1001',
      lineItems: {
        edges: [ { node: { name: 'dance mat red', quantity: 4 } } ]
      }
    }
  },`

Comment: No problem, practice makes perfect. ```forEach``` can be used to iterate over arrays, and in your new JSON node is actually an object, we should actually iterate over edges (not node). such as: ```const flatten = items.map(item => {
  const { node } = item;
  const i = {
    name: node.name,
    createdAt: node.createdAt,
  };

  node.lineItems.edges.forEach(product => {
    const n = product.node;
    i[n.name] = n.quantity;
  });

  return i;
});```. Also mark the answer as accepted so other can finds it. Cheers!

Comment: Wow again MAS, seriously impressive, thats working well, I am very luckily to have you find this question, thanks a million for you help/expertise - respect.